# isPlaceholder modifier not available and not working in widget kit + SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit, wwdc

I am following the widgets code along Fromm wwdc 2020 and in the first part they mentioned using the new Placeholder api with `.isPlacholder`. So I tried implementing it in my widget like this:

```swift
struct PlaceholderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RandomWidgetView(book: testBook)
            .isPlaceholder(true)
    }
}
```

however I get the error `Value of type 'RandomWidgetView' has no member 'isPlaceholder'`. After googling I found this:

```swift
struct PlaceholderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RandomWidgetView(book: testBook)
            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
    }
}
```

However this doesn't create the correct placeholders but instead just removes the views inside completely.

Am I missing an import or was it changed since wwdc? How do I create the correct placeholders?

Answer (score 7):

In your Widget extension you should have code that looks something like this, which as I have it here is just the default Widget implementation. If you place your `.redacted(reason: .placeholder)` in the view where you have the `Provider.Entry` it should give you the results you're looking for.

```
// other TimelineProvider code...

struct RandomWidgetViewEntryView: View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
    }
}

@main
struct RandomWidgetView: Widget {
    let kind: String = "RandomWidgetView"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            RandomWidgetViewEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

[image: placeholder image view]

Answer (score 1):

The initial `.isPlaceholder(_:)` API had changed in the iOS 14 beta 3 to `.redacted(reason:)` API and this is the reason the compiler does not recognise the `isPlaceholder` calls.

Here is how to use it correctly: [How to mark content as a placeholder using redacted()](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-mark-content-as-a-placeholder-using-redacted)